# How do I extrude a modified curve (circle, plane)

Tags: extrude

[image]

Hi! I've modified 5 segment circle into a star and used a Solidify modifier to add thickness. Now how can I extrude it in order to give it vertical depth? In 3ds max you could do this by simply applying the Extrude modifier but being new to Blender can't wrap my head around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mesh is not pathological, i.e.its intersections really are intersections, with vertices:

[image]

Then you can either extrude the edges by hand in Z *before* solidifying, or do it with standard modifiers as follows...

*Screw* with no rotation is an extrusion:

[image]

Followed by *Solidify* with zero offset:

[image]